# best practices for java fx application build tool for linux

Tags: linux, javafx-8, rpm, centos6

I trying to write a JavaFX application. When I built it using Netbeans, the RPM package does not work on CentOS 6.

Is there any fool proof way to build a JavaFX application for Linux?

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** I'm the maintainer of the [javafx-maven-plugin](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin) and creator of the [javafx-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/FibreFoX/javafx-gradle-plugin)

When using maven, you can use the javafx-maven-plugin, just set the `<bundler>` to "rpm":

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>8.4.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>your.path.to.your.MainClass</mainClass>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <bundler>rpm</bundler>
        <bundleArguments>
            <licenseFile>license.rtf</licenseFile>
        </bundleArguments>
        <!-- place your license here -->
        <additionalAppResources>src/main/additionalAppResources</additionalAppResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then just call `mvn jfx:native` on the command-line to create your rpm-package having your application including the JRE inside. If you don't want the JRE sit inside the RPM-package, just add `<runtime />` to the bundleArguments.

When using gradle, just look at the project-website on github ;) or ask me via mail if something is unclear.

**EDIT**
As a temporary workaround, please set appName to something without a dot

```
    <configuration>
        <!-- other configuration elements -->
        <appName>SimpleApplicationNameWithoutDot</appName>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: There seems to be some bug .. opened issue-ticket on this: https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin/issues/205

Comment: its still not working, after implementing changes... may be i need to debug my Centos installation, but not able to get system logs unfortunately

Comment: As described on the other channels: I get a working RPM by using the [sample project](https://github.com/gclouds/simplejavafxApp/) with my modifications. Just created a simple CentOS-virtual machine, installed Oracle-JDK, installed Netbeans (for JavaSE), opened that maven-project and clicked "clean and build". The result is working reproducable. Please try to verify that on that sample-project, not on your real-work-project ;) maybe something else is wrong there

Comment: For all readers: this is fixed/worked around with javafx-maven-plugin 8.5.0

Comment: Thanks :) but some how it was not working with external libs